# Angular-route issues - Route not executing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I've been following a set of tutorials from Scott Allen. I have tried to emulate what he does down to the bone I believe however my angular route is just not being executed.

I have a view called main.html and a shell/layout view called index.html. Inside the index.html I have ng-view in the body tag and I have a route in a script file called app.js as follows:

```
(function(){

  var app = angular.module("githubViewer", ["ngRoute"]);

  app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/main", {
          templateUrl: "main.html",
          controller: "MainController"
        })
        .when("/user/:username", {
          templateUrl: "user.html",
          controller: "UserController"
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo:"/main"});
  });

}());
```

Here is the index.html's script imports

```
 <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-route.js"></script>
```

The way I know that the route isn't being hit is because the main.html's code isn't being passed back to the page.

Has something perhaps changed in the way the angular-route is used?

Also here is a link to my plunk : http://plnkr.co/edit/Ew73QexRoDZlrvPG2UA1?p=preview

Comment: You're using angular 1.3 beta along with ng-route 1.2. Not sure if this is the issue but you should use the same version.

Comment: I had tried that as per reccomendation of someone a little more experienced with angularjs however it didnt rectify the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating same angular module multiple times. Creating same angular module number of times just fails. So, create angular module once and use it in other places as follows

```
var app = angular.module('FirstModule');  // app.js
app.controller // controller.js
app.factory  // service.js
app.directive  // directives.js
```

Here is the updated plunkr.

http://plnkr.co/edit/qWHkzj9v6nGhhb7MjDDf?p=preview

I have changed the following self executing function to normal functions as they create closures and the module created in app.js is not available in other files.

```
(function(){

}());
```

Otherwise, you can pass module created in app.js as parameter to all self executing functions in other files.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Euoir8q4kdCIEJTDlGBs?p=preview). You used to call `angular.module` again and as a setter instead of using it as a getter.

EDIT:
I'm one minute late =) You can use Vikram Babu's answer and remove the wrapping closures completely. IF you need to use the closures just use `var app = angular.module("githubViewer");` instead of `var app = angular.module("githubViewer", []);` in order not to overwrite the module definition.